# Download List - Mac Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, download

It would be far to much for me to ask for a full solution. However, could you point me in the right direction in what I need to look up, learn etc as its the first time I am going to attempt something like this.

What I want to do, is in my Mac application, have a list of items which are files which I want to store online. Then from inside the application the user can download any of the items stored at that location online. If I add new items to download online I want the app to automatically add them to the list for download.

That make sense? Anyway, its the first time I have done anything like this using an online server and accessing it via an app, so any support would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want an ftp type server, you can then get list of remote files, upload and download file, if you do search for Cocoa ftp I am sure you will find someone has written a nice wrapper class for ftp, there are even complete open source apps for ftp whose code you can examine, [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/), other you could just use NSTask, and call the ftp command line tool on all macs.

Comment: Would HTTP not be more efficient than FTP?

Comment: If you want to use HTTP then you will have to write/acquire a server app that can handle you request to send and retrieve files. FTP does this already, I don't know what you mean by efficient, work load for you no, unless you already have a server app written for you. If you mean efficient network wise, I wouldn't know, but I don't see why ftp should be any less efficient. If you are referring to your front end Cocoa app, and to using NSTask, you could try using NSConnection etc to do ftp perhaps, but the overhead in using NSTask is nothing in comparison to network speed.